# do/did/would do/could do?

Tags: grammar

Lets say you bought a new device and found out that it cant do one of the things you were hoping for. Which of the following can be said and which one is best.         
 1. "I thought it does that."
 2. "I thought it did that."
 3. "I thought it would do that."
 4. "I thought it could do that."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the purchaser *held the mistaken belief* it had specific functionality, but discovered it did not, the fourth option would be my recommendation.

If the purchaser of the device was *hoping* (implying uncertainty) it had specific functionality, but discovered it did not, I'd replace "thought" with "hoped" in the fourth option.